# Visual Studio 2015 "lowlighting" redundant code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio's Dark color theme.
Since I switched from VS2012 to VS2015, redundant code (e.g. "Me" in Visual Basic) is made darker blue than all the rest of the key words.
I like the "Me" keyword, and I don't want to see it a different color.
Is there a way to turn off this feature?
(I.e. is there a way to stop VS from recommending to me that I remove the "Me" keyword by making it darker blue)?

Answer (score 4):

1. From the menu choose Tools > Options
2. Select Text Editor > Basic > Code Style
3. Check Qualify member access with 'Me'

Answer (score 1):

- Go to References in your project
- Right click on Analyzer -> Open Active Rule Set
- In `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features` uncheck IDE0003, which is responsible for "removing `this` and `Me`

[image: example]